# ServiceAccount cannot list resource "pods" in namespace though it has role with appropriate resources

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rbac

I have the following definitions in my custom namespace:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: test-sa
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: test
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods", "pods/exec"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "delete", "patch", "create"]
  - apiGroups: ["extensions", "apps"]
    resources: ["deployments", "deployments/scale"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "delete", "patch", "create"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: test
subjects:
  - kind: User
    name: test-sa
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: test
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Running `describe role test`

```
Name:         test
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                {"apiVersion":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1","kind":"Role","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"test","namespace":"test-namesapce...
PolicyRule:
  Resources                     Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------                     -----------------  --------------  -----
  pods/exec                     []                 []              [get list delete patch create]
  pods                          []                 []              [get list delete patch create]
  deployments.apps/scale        []                 []              [get list delete patch create]
  deployments.apps              []                 []              [get list delete patch create]
  deployments.extensions/scale  []                 []              [get list delete patch create]
  deployments.extensions        []                 []              [get list delete patch create]
```

When I'm trying to run the command `kubectl get pods` in a pod that is using this service account, I'm getting the following error:

> Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User
>   "system:serviceaccount:test-namespace:test-sa" cannot list resource
>   "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "test-namespace"

Where is that misconfigured?

Comment: `kubectl auth  can-i get pods --as system:serviceaccount:test-namespace:test-sa` can you try this ?

Comment: @SureshVishnoi the response is a clear `no`

Comment: your rolebinding should be in the `test-namespace`

Comment: did it work for you now with rolebinding?

Comment: @SureshVishnoi the `RoleBinding` is already in this namespace, do you mean I should specify it also for the `subjects` or `roleRef`? didn't see any note of that in documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was with the `subjects` of `RoleBinding`. The correct definition would be:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: test
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: test-sa
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: test
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Comment: I have the same issue, this doesn't work for me, I get : *The RoleBinding "dev-access" is invalid: subjects[0].apiGroup: Unsupported value: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io": supported values: ""*

Comment: how to create a user instead of serviceAccount??

Comment: @KhalilMeg you shouldn't use a user for such things

Comment: I want to give access to another person with edit clusterRole, should I use ServiceAccount or user, how to do it please

Comment: @KhalilMeg best practice is to use a service account. You can authenticate with the SA using gcloud sdk: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account

Comment: I’m not using a cloud platform